# I'm stuck in Zi, what now?

Tags: axiom-verge

I reached the first save point in Zi and I'm kind of stuck.

[image]

There is this ledge I can't jump past: (the bubbles make the "you can't glitch this yet" sound)

[image]

A little west of it there's a ledge too high to reach, a door behind a wall I can't glitch.

West of the savepoint there is the rest of the game, but the way back is behind a gap too large for me to bridge.

What now?

Answer (score 2):

The purple vegetation there reduces your jump height. If you destroy it, or attempt the jump from further back, you can clear the jump in the picture.